# how to get $this value in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

In message variable I am getting the multiple selected, how to store them in array, after this store in database?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#lstFruits').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
        $('#btnSelected').click(function () {
            var selected = $("#lstFruits option:selected");
            // document.write(selected);

            //.var array = string.split(",").val(selected);

            var message = "";
            selected.each(function () {
                message += $(this).val();
                // here I am getting the selected ids like 2,4,5 and I
                // want to submit all ids in the database. 
                // While, when I am submitting currently only the last 
                // id is being submitted.
                var vale = [$(this).val()];
                //document.write(vale);
                $('#second').val(vale);
            });
            alert(message);
        });
    });

</script>
```

How to store all selected values in array and then submit in php page by query?

Comment: What do you expect `$(this)` to be? Do you expect it to be `$('#btnSelected')`?

Comment: i have a selected form  with check box value with that javascript code ,so i want to store multiple check box value in database, the messgae showing on alert all values.

Comment: So what do you expect `$(this)` to be?

Comment: Are you maybe just looking for `vale.push($(this).val())`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the values in array & name of the field whose id is second should be like second[]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#lstFruits').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
        $('#btnSelected').click(function () {
            var selected = $("#lstFruits option:selected");
            var message = [];
            selected.each(function () {
                message.push($(this).val());
            });
            $('#second').val(message);
            alert(message);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Maybe `var message = [];` should be a global outside the function? otherwise you reset the array every time a button gets clicked, there would only be one element in the array at every single time.

Comment: does the alert gives all the values

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="second"  name="room_id" /> i am getting that id in hidden, and that submitting ito the databse.

Comment: Try like this <input type="hidden" id="second" name="room_id[]">

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can submit this to php by [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). (With GET or POST query)
[Another guide about ajax](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/ajax-deferreds)

Example

```
  $.post('yourphpfile.php', {data: JSON.stringify(message)})
  .done(function(data) { console.log('success'); })
  .fail(function() { console.log('error');
```

// in youphpfile.php

```
 $_POST['data'] ? yourFunctionToInsert($_POST['method']) : null;
```

btw, to insert in array in your js file,  you can also do:

```
  message[] = $(this).val(); //in the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('#lstFruits').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });

    //create array variable
    var selectedValues = new Array();
    $('#btnSelected').click(function () {
        var selected = $("#lstFruits option:selected");
       selectedValues.push(selected);

      //then by use=ing ajax you can send this array
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           data: {info:selectedValues},
           url: "page.php",
           success: function(msg){
             $('.answer').html(msg);
           }
        });

    });
});
```

You can make array then by useing .push method can store values in array, after that by ajax you can send over PHP page.

Comment: how to get from  ajax , i want  to get the output on same page , i am new in ajax.